# Is it possible to edit/shorten the tabbed window names in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to edit/shorten the tabbed window names in Visual Studio? For instance, can "Solution Explorer" be shortened to just "Solution"? And "Document Outline" to simply "Outline"?

See screenshot below.

I already think the answer is "no", but I wanted to ask anyways to be certain.

I suppose a convoluted way to accomplish this is create a Visual Studio Add-In that accesses the IDE Extensibility and alters the pane tab captions, but I'm not certain, as I'm not that advanced yet.

Thank you.

[image]